# How to return Observable after some Promise get resolved in Ionic 2/Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I am trying to return an observable after a successful completion of my Promise, but that function is not returning Observable. 
To be specific to code, i want to fetch auth token from storage (returns promise) and after that data got fetched then generate a Post request to Api (returns Observable). By doing so, sublime text gives an error on function that "a function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value"
below is my code,

```
logout() : Observable<any>{
  this.userData.getAuthToken().then((token)=>{
    this.token = token;
    this.headers = new Headers ({
      "X-USER-TOKEN": token
    });
    this.options = new RequestOptions ({
      headers: this.headers
    });
    var logout_url = "Api logout method";
    return this.http.post(logout_url,{},this.options)
      .map (res => res.json())
  });
}
```

if i simply do a post request then it returns fine like this

```
return this.http.post(logout_url,{},this.options)
  .map (res => res.json())
```

but when i try to fetch data it do not return value from this post request.
Any help will be much Appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use [`fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise) to convert the promise into an observable and use [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) to emit the HTTP response into the composed observable:

```ta
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable/';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

logout(): Observable<any>{
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.userData.getAuthToken()).mergeMap(token => {
    this.token = token;
    this.headers = new Headers({
      "X-USER-TOKEN": token
    });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: this.headers
    });
    var logout_url = "Api logout method";
    return this.http.post(logout_url, {}, this.options).map(res => res.json());
  });
}
```

Comment: this solution looks good but it gives an error saying _TypeError: Observable_2.fromPromise is not a function._ Although i posted short hand version of my function in question. Function after updating with fromPromise and mergeMap is posted above. Plz take a look does it look fine ?

Comment: Added the necessary imports to the answer.

Answer (score 25):

With RXJS>6, `fromPromise` is merged into `from` function and to use `mergeMap`, you need to use `pipe` first. So this code will work

```js
    import { Observable, from } from "rxjs";
    import { map, mergeMap } from "rxjs/operators";
    
    logout(): Observable<any>{
      return from(this.userData.getAuthToken()).pipe(mergeMap(token => {
        this.token = token;
        this.headers = new Headers({
          "X-USER-TOKEN": token
        });
        this.options = new RequestOptions({
          headers: this.headers
        });
        var logout_url = "Api logout method";
        return this.http.post(logout_url, {}, this.options).map(res => res.json());
      }));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would be returning a `Promise` (if you hadn't missed the `return` part in front of it) which would return an `Observable` on success. Consider using `Observables` only, rather than mixing them both.

You can also encapsulate it into a new `Observable`: `new Observable(observer =>`
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html

Comment: The promise is returning an observable,true.. But `logout` doesnt return anything..

Comment: yes, ionic 2 storage returns promise of successful retrieval of data from storage and then angular 2 http post method returns Observable. the main thing is that how can i directly return something from inside promise success ? Although can you plz share code snippet of converting to Observable only ? it might help to solve the issue.

Comment: @M.Habib promises are async, you are already returning an `Observable` but you still have to wait for the `Promise` to finish. You can either do something like it shows on the example I linked or look at @cartant answer.

Comment: @zurfyx Can you please explain why promise returning observable. I expected return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {});  to return Promise but its returning Observable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from **Sunil** worked for my use case, this is my working example. I am using this in my http interceptor to append acces token to the HTTP request

```js
import {from, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {mergeMap} from "rxjs/operators";

 handleTokenExpiration(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.isAccessTokenPresent()) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getAccessToken()}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(request);
    } else {
      if (this.isRefreshTokenPresent()) {
        return from(this.refreshToken(this.getRefreshToken())).pipe(mergeMap(res => {
          request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getAccessToken()}`
            }
          });
          return next.handle(request);
        }));
      } else {
        this.logout();
      }
    }
  }
```