# How can I convert an ionic http GET request from @angular\Http to @ion-native\Http?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework

I'm looking to convert this request, which is using angular/http, so that I can get results on a physical device:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; //old way
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http'; //new way
```

The angular/http request

```
function getWeather() {
     return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + latitude + ',' + longitude)
         .map(res => res.json());
   }
```

The method that is making the call, using 'subscribe'

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(latitude, longitude).subscribe(results => {
   console.log(results);
});
```

I am wanting to convert this to native/http, available as a plugin in Ionic

It might look something like this:

```
function getWeather() {
     return this.httpNative.get(this.url + '/' + latitude + ',' + longitude, {}, {})
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.data); 

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.error); 
        });
    }
```

However, I am having some issues receiving the data in this method, as I can no longer subscribe to the result and it is not being mapped... I receive null results

```
this.weatherProvider.getWeather(latitude, longitude).subscribe(results => {
   console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/), get returns a promise... but for "subscribe" (in order to use this.weatherProvider.getWeather(latitude, longitude).subscribe())... you need to return an observable from Promise

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585514/how-to-return-observable-after-some-promise-get-resolved-in-ionic-2-angular-2) should be able to get you what you're looking for...