# Angular cache http in local storage

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic4

On Ionic 4 Angular 8 project, I try to get information in storage before call API.

Here is my code

```
public getData(id) {
    return this.storage.get(id).then(
        content => {
            if (content == null) {
                return this.getObject(id).subscribe(
                    result => {
                        return result;
                    }
                );
            } else {
                return content;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

How can I call the function 'getData ?

```
myService.getData(id).then
```

This return string or observable I should subscribe, how to handle both cases ?

Comment: Put your string in an Observable with the `of` operator from RxJS to standardize your method call. Moreover, you should put a return type on your method & use RxJS Observable not promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using RxJS 6, I would recommend you to convert the promise into an observable (using the [from](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html) operator), and then handle the subsequent operations using pipeable operators, such as `tap`, or `switchMap`, depending on the desired behaviour of your method. In this case, we can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), since we are returning an observable.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getData(id) {
  return from(this.storage.get(id))
    .pipe(
      switchMap(content => {
        if (content === null) {
          return this.getObject(id);
        } else {
          return of(content);
        }
      }),
    )
}
```

From there, you can subscribe to the `getData` and return the observables.

```
myService.getData(id).subscribe((res) => {
  // do the rest here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this ?

```js
public getData(id): Observable<any> {
  return this.storage.get(id)
    .then(content => {
      if (content === null) {
        return this.getObject(id);
      } else {
        return of(content);
      }
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to call it like :

```js
myService.getData(id).subscribe(console.log);
```

**UPDATE**

Could you try with this ?

```js
getData(id): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get(id)).switchMap(content => {
    if (content === null) {
      return this.getObject(id);
    } else {
      return of(content);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I copied your code and got this error : "TS2740: Type 'Promise<Observable<any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more."

Comment: I updated my code, replacing ternary if. Does it give you the same error ?

Comment: I updated my post. Please check. I found this in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585514/how-to-return-observable-after-some-promise-get-resolved-in-ionic-2-angular-2)

Comment: TS2339: Property 'fromPromise' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. But if I remove "Observable<any>" on your previous code and chain .then and .subscribe it work as well

Comment: Alright ! I'm not used to Promise (: If your problem is solved, feel free to edit my post, adding working code :)